# Why do I have to use a fear as the Alternative-Hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

## Introduction

I'd like to understand, why I have to use a fear as the Alternative-Hypothesis
and not as the Null-Hypothesis. I'm using my homework as an example for that,
which says the following (I translated it manually, I hope that you can
understand the exercise):

```
A big band finds out that one CD from their first 20 CDs has a wrong cover on
it. Now they're afraid that at least 5% of all covers are wrong. So they
want to start a significance test with a significance niveau of 10% and with
the Null-Hypothesis: "The share of the wrong covers is smaller than 5%". If the
result shows that their fear is true, they will ask the producer to sell the
CDs for a lower price.

a) Explain why they chose this Null-Hypothesis.
```

The solution says, that they chose this Null-Hypothesis in order to be able to limit
the risk of the error, but I'm wondering why it isn't possible to do that with
the Hypothesis: "The share of the wrong covers is at least 5%.". Because this
would let to these two Hypothesis:

$$
H_{0}: p \geq 0{,}05 \\
H_{1}: p < 0{,}05
$$

But the correct way would be:

$$
H_{0}: p < 0{,}05 \\
H_{1}: p \geq 0{,}05
$$

Now let's stick to the "correct way" for a moment and assume that I'd do a
Hypothesis test, I'd look at the "corner-case" of the Null-Hypothesis, so $H_{0}
= p < 0{,}05 = p = 0{,}05$. After that I can calculate the "area", which helps
me to decide when I can *reject* the Null-Hypothesis and when not, by finding
out how many CDs have a wrong cover:

$$
P\left(X \geq k | p = 0{,}05\right) \leq 0{,}1
$$

So the region of rejection would be:

$$
R = \left\{k, \ldots, n\right\}
$$

where:

- $n$ is the amount of the CDs which are used in the Hypothesis test and
- $k$ is the least border-value where we reject our Null-Hypothesis or in other
  words: The minimal amount of CDs which have a wrong cover, where we reject the
  Null-Hypothesis.
- $X$ represents the amount of CDs which have a wrong cover

So far so good, that makes sense for me: We're calculating the
rejecting-areas to be able to conclude if the result of our test would be the
same as if we'd test all CDs which they sold.

**EDIT (1)**:

Little "addition" to the conclusion here: We've calculated now our
rejecting-areas to be able to decide if our fear (the Alternative-Hypothesis) is
"true" (or "valid") or not by testing it on our dataset of $n$ CDs. If it turns
out that our fear is "true", so our dataset landed in our rejection-area, we can
think, that our fear (the Alternative-Hypothesis) has a probability to be the
"better" assumption than the Null-Hypothesis. But it could change, if we'd do
more tests and the "hit-rate" of the Null-Hypothesis increases and becomes
bigger than the Alternative-Hypothesis so that's why we can't say, that this
hypothesis is "the absolute correct one". That's correct, right?

## Question

Now I'm wondering: Why I can't just use their fear as the Null-Hypothesis
(my first two Hypothesis)? I can do the same steps as before like in the
"correct way" and get a rejecting-area for my Null-Hypothesis as well. This
would lead to the following Hypothesis test:

$$
P\left(X \leq k | p = 0{,}05 \right) \leq 0{,}1
$$

After finding a suitable value for $k$, I'd have this rejection-area:

$$
R = \left\{0, \ldots, k\right\}
$$

Which can be intrepreted like this(?): "If there are at least $k$ CDs with a
wrong cover of $n$ CDs, than I can be sure that there are only at the most 5% of
all CDs with a wrong cover." What's my wrong thought?

## Which external sources have you tried out?

I watched [StatQuest's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5koKb5B_YWo&t=0s) about the alternative Hypothesis and in
[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5koKb5B_YWo&t=459s) part, he explained that you can't assume that our alternative
Hypothesis is right since it includes "all" alternative Hypothesis (if we're
using the correct way). I understood his explanation about his example, but I
can't get a "connection" from his example to my problem/homework. Didn't I
showed, that $H_{0}: p \geq 0{,}05$ is true if I found more than $k$ wrong CDs
according to my (wrong) Hypothesis test? Didn't I show in this Hypothesis test,
that no matter which other Alternative Hypothesises are included in the Alternative
Hypothesis, they all have $p \geq 0{,}05$?

## Summary

### The correct one

$$
H_{0}: p < 0{,}05\\
H_{1}: p \geq 0{,}05
$$

Our rejection-area:

$$
R = \left\{k, \ldots, n\right\}
$$

Interpretation of our result:

1. We get into our rejection-area $\to$ The possibility of our **null**
   hypothesis is **smaller** than the **alternative** hypothesis.

   In other words: 
   The possibility that there are **at most** 5% of the CDs with
   a wrong cover in a dataset is **smaller** than the possibility that **at
   least** 5% of the CDs have a wrong cover.
2. We *don't* get into our rejection-are $\to$ The possibility of our **null**
   hypothesis is **greater** than the **alternative** hypothesis.

   In other words: 
   The possibility that there are **at most** 5% of the CDs with a wrong cover
   in a dataset is **greater** than the possibility that **at least** 5% of the
   CDs have a wrong cover.

### The "false" one

$$
H_{0}: p \geq 0{,}05 \\
H_{1}: p < 0{,}05
$$

Our rejection area:

$$
R = \left\{0, \ldots, k\right\}
$$

Interpretation of our result:

1. We get into our rejection-area $\to$ The possibility of our **null**
   hypothesis is **smaller** than the **alternative** hypothesis.

   In other words: 
   The possibility that there are **at most** 5% of the CDs with a wrong cover
   in a dataset is **greater** than the possibility that **at least** 5% of the
   CDs have a wrong cover.
2. We *don't* get into our rejection-are $\to$ The possibility of our **null**
   hypothesis is **greater** than the **alternative** hypothesis.

   In other words: 
   The possibility that there are **at most** 5% of the CDs with a wrong cover
   in a dataset is **smaller** than the possibility that **at least** 5% of the
   CDs have a wrong cover.

I achieved in both cases the same result, correct? So why is it *not* possible to
chose the "false" one?

Comment: The alternative hypothesis is the thing that you want to prove. Suppose that your alternative hypothesis is that fewer than 5% of all covers are wrong. There are two possible outcomes: 1) You might prove the alternative hypothesis, in which case you will take no action. 2) You might not prove the alternative hypothesis, in which case you also take no action because you haven't proved anything. If you do the hypothesis test that way, there's no way you're going to take action. Remember, failing to reject the null hypothesis does not mean that we believe the null hypothesis is true.

Comment: `You might prove the alternative hypothesis` and `in which case you also take no action because you haven't proved anything.` are mindblowing for me at the moment. How can I imagine that? `failing to reject the null hypothesis does not mean that we believe the null hypothesis is true.` But isn't that the reason why we do a hypothesis test? We create a hypothesis and look, if we can reject this hypotheses or not, according to our "conditions" by the reject-areas.

Comment: Failing to reject the null hypothesis merely means that the data we observed is consistent with the null hypothesis. In other words, the data we observed does not contradict the null hypothesis. It doesn't mean the null hypothesis is actually true. Rejecting the null hypothesis is much more exciting than failing to reject the null hypothesis. It means that the data we observed is not consistent with the null hypothesis, which means that we have strong evidence that the alternative hypothesis is actually true.

Comment: Ok, so I think that I understand what you mean: If we'd repeat this test 10
times and the first 4 tests "confirm" that our null hypothesis is right, 
doesn't mean that our null hypothesis is true, because the 6 left test could
"confirm" that the null hypothesis is "false", right? So your explanation makes
sense for me but still: I don't really understand, why it isn't possible to do
the same but the other way around by "proving" the alternative hypothesis.

Comment: Here's one example that might help think about what it means when we fail to reject the null hypothesis. Suppose a woman has been murdered at her home and our alternative hypothesis is that her husband did it. The null hypothesis is that he didn't do it. We look at the evidence -- he has no motive, no history of violent crime. His DNA was found on the scene but he lives there. We are unable to convict. We can't reject the null hypothesis. It doesn't mean the man is actually innocent, though. Maybe he is, maybe he isn't. All we know is we don't have enough evidence to convict.

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to wait until someone who is more expert in statistics chimes in. There are probably other ways to explain this that are more enlightening.

Comment: But if I assume, that our null hypothesis is that her husband is the murder and we
don't have a motive, nor a history of violent crimes as well. Neither I can
reject the null-hypothesis nor can I "accept" the null-hypothesis, because the
situation is too unclear. So isn't that the same as your hypothesis, because I can't
reject my as well? `Anyway, I'm going to wait until someone who is more expert in statistics chimes in.` Ok, but thank you for the "discussion"! Saying that the hypothesis test works only for our current dataset improved my understanding about its meaning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so me and my friends "found" the reason now.

Let's pick up the "wrong" Hypothesis first:

$$
H_{0}: p \geq 0{,}05 \\
H_{1}: p < 0{,}05 \\
A = \left\{0, \ldots, k\right\}
$$

So let's go through both cases:

- Assume **we land** into our rejecting-area $A$. This would mean, that we'll reject
  $H_{0}$ because its possibility is too small for our current dataset. So we
  assume that the possibility, that there are **at most** $5\%$ wrong CDs, is
  **higher** than the possibility that there are **at least** $5\%$ wrong CDs.
  As a result, we will do "nothing" because we think that there are at least
  $5\%$ of all CDs with a wrong cover.
- Assume **we don't land** into our rejecting-area $A$. This would mean, that
  the possiblity of $H_{0}$ is too big that we can't reject this hypothesis.
  Of course you could say, that we have to go to the producer now and demand
  him to reduce the price of each CD since we showed that it's possible that
  at least $5\%$ of all CDs have a wrong cover.

  **BUT:** 
  We calculated the rejection-area *for $p = 0{,}05$* as a
  *limit-possibility*! So what happens, if $p$ is actually $0{,}9$? This would
  mean that our rejection-area *would be actually larger* as we've set it now!
  So we can't demand the producer to reduce the price of the CDs, even if we
  found $k + 1$ CDs ($k$ is our calculated value for $p = 0{,}05$)
  with a wrong cover because $p$ might be actually *greater* so we wouldn't be
  actually in the rejection-area if $p = 0{,}99$ for example.

So we didn't achieve anything with these two results if we'd choose the
Hypothesis like that.

Now let's pick up the "correct" Hypothesis:

$$
H_{0}: p < 0{,}05 \\
H_{1}: p \geq 0{,}05 \\
A = \left\{k, \ldots, 150\right\}
$$

This would lead to the following cases:

- Assume **we land** into our rejection-area $A$. This would mean that our
  Hypothesis $H_{0}$ has a too small probability for our current dataset and
  we can think that our Hypothesis $H_{1}$ is "true" so we *need* to demand
  the producer to reduce the price of the CDs. You could compare this case
  with the second assuming of the wrong Hypothesis and say: "But we don't know
  what $p$ is." But in this case, it doesn't matter what $p$ is since we
  assume that $p$ is smaller than $0{,}05$! If $p$ would be $0{,}02$ or
  $0{,}04$ our rejection-area would just go further *to the left* (so k
  becomes smaller) and if our current test included $k$ wrong CDs, we would
  still be in the rejection-area if $p$ is actually smaller than $0{,}05$!
  That's why we have to chose our fear as the alternative Hypothesis :)
- Assume **we don't land** into our rejection-area $A$. This would mean that we
  can't reject our $H_{0}$ Hypothesis because its probability is not small
  enough to be seen as "not possible" for our current dataset. As a result: We
  don't know what we should do, since both Hypothesises are possible.

I hope that this explanation is clear enough (*and not wrong*).